# How can I get to know the numbers of rows or records my table is consisting (row count)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

If I have number of tables in my database and I want to know the number of records that table is consisting.
What I have done so far is:

```
 Select name as Product from sysobjects where xtype='U'
 order by name
```

and I got the total tables. 
eg.

```
Product
--------
apple
nokia
sony
samsung
motorola
```

How to find the total number of records the table is containing?

Answer (score 1):

got it.

```
Select distinct obj.name,i.rowcnt as product from sysobjects obj 
 inner join sysindexes i 
 on obj.id=i.id
 where  xtype='U' and rowcnt>0
 order by i.rowcnt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

use count() function to fetch total number of records

Select count(*) from tablename;

Comment: its fine when I want number of records for only one particular table.

Comment: i wrote wrong query first time, sorry. 
i corrected that just now.